# Blender won't start on Tails 1.4 (Debian)

Tags: linux

```
amnesia@amnesia:~/Desktop/blender-2.74-linux-glibc211-x86_64$ ls
2.74                    GPL3-license.txt       LICENSE-bmonofont-i18n.ttf.txt
blender                 GPL-license.txt        LICENSE-droidsans.ttf.txt
blenderplayer           icons                  Python-license.txt
blender-softwaregl      jemalloc-license.txt   readme.html
blender-thumbnailer.py  lib
copyright.txt           LICENSE-bfont.ttf.txt
amnesia@amnesia:~/Desktop/blender-2.74-linux-glibc211-x86_64$ ./blender
bash: ./blender: No such file or directory
```

I'm an actual Linux noob and googled for install instructions. I use Tails 1.4 which is Debian.

Comment: Does the `blender` executable actually have execute permissions? Try running `ls -l`, `blender` should have something like `rwxr-xr-x` next to it. (at least the `x`'s)

Comment: @gandalf3 blender has '-rwxr-xr-x'. Btw I was confused to see in text and video tutorials that one just has to start the exe from the folder because I remember Linux not to be able to use .exe but with "wine". Trying to open the executable(mouse click on file) does not do anything either.

Comment: Linux doesn't have `.exe` files (that's a windows/dos convention). `blender` is a binary executable (pretty much a `.exe` file for linux). As to why bash thinks it's missing, thats really weird..

Comment: I'm not even a mod...

Comment: @Jonathan Could you post the output of `uname -a` and `file ./blender`? The [Tails download page](https://tails.boum.org/download/index.en.html#index2h1) only has 32-bit images as far as I can tell, so it might be that you need to use the 32-bit version of Blender.

Comment: Also check that the filesystem containing the blender executable isn't mounted with the `noexec` option.

Comment: @catlover2 If you look at ls command above, you'll see that it's a 64bit version of Blender. You should write up an answer.

Comment: I got curious and ran Tails in a VM to test this. It is indeed 32-bit, but, for some reason, I got a different (and more descriptive) error when trying to run the 64-bit executable: `bash: ./blender: cannot execute binary file`. In any case, 32-bit Blender worked as expected with no error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to run a 64-bit version of Blender on a 32-bit system. Go to [download.blender.org](http://www.blender.org/download/), click on the "GNU/Linux" tab, and click the 32-bit button. Then, extract the archive and run the blender executable.

For a more in-depth explanation of the error message, check out [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13409/54559) on unix.stackexchange.com.